# Sorting div by ID or class

Tags: jquery, html, reverse

How to sort this div by ID with jquery?

```
<div id="p38" class="p33">Test</div>
<div id="p35" class="p33">Test</div>
<div id="p45" class="p45">Test2</div>
<div id="p33" class="p33">Test</div>
```

Im now using this js

```
    function callMeOften()
    {
         $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url : '1.php',
            dataType : 'text',
            success: function (text) {
                $('#updateMe').html(text)  ;
            }
        });
    }
    var holdTheInterval = setInterval(callMeOften, 5000);

$(".p<? echo $userRank['userID'] ?>").appendTo("#statMSG1").filter(".p<? echo $userRank['userID'] ?>:gt(0)").remove();
    });
```

Actually i get new results from 1.php as can you see above.. and new results always appears at bottom , i need to reverse results and new must be on top

Comment: Classnames cannot begin with a digit. Your classes are invalid.

Comment: Should be done at the **server side** if possible.

Comment: @Truth: true for HTML other than HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use `prependTo()` instead of `appendTo()`:

```
$(".p<? echo $userRank['userID'] ?>").prependTo("#statMSG1").filter(".p<? echo $userRank['userID'] ?>:gt(0)").remove();
});
```

Comment: Well, if that's made it work you could consider up-voting or accepting. (Don't feel compelled to, but if the question's been answered it helps to mark it as solved. Otherwise, leave it open for a while to get alternative answers). Anyway, I'm glad to have been of help, and you're absolutely welcome! =)